# Is the convolution of $L^2$ functions continuous?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-transform, convolution

Is the answer to the following question positive?
[The convolution of two $L^2(\mathbb R)$ functions is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915085/the-convolution-of-two-l2-mathbb-r-functions-is-continuous)

I briefly recall it here:
Take $f$ and $g$ $\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, then I want to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_\mathbb{R} f(x-y-h)g(y)dy = f \ast g(x)$.

The question has an answer but it has not been accepted yet.

Comment: Yes https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915085/the-convolution-of-two-l2-mathbb-r-functions-is-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The answer there is correct and it has been upvoted many times. Some askers don't care to  approve answers and the questions remain  in the unanswered list